# checking the existence of a neighbor Android fragment

Tags: android

I'd like to check the existence of a neighbor fragment from an Android fragment code.  I tried this but both show `false` even there is another fragment with an ID `R.id.blank2`.

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        Fragment f = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.blank2);
        hasNeighbor = f != null;
        Log.i("vac", "OnCreateView: " + hasNeighbor);

        f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.blank2);
        hasNeighbor = f != null;
        Log.i("vac", "OnCreateView: " + hasNeighbor);
```

I'm using android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

This is a layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:name="com.vac.myapplication.BlankFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/blank"/>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.vac.myapplication.BlankFragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/blank2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe include a callback in fragment2 to fragment1 to notify of its creation.

Answer (score 1):

`getFragmentManager()` is correct, but check the order of instantiate (order in layout xml). `BlankFragment2` isn't yet created when you try to find it.